# Is it possible to read an empty string from cin and still get true from cin.good()?

Tags: c++, cin

My question is based on this simple code:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string buf;
    while (cin >> buf && !buf.empty()) {
        cout << "input is " << buf << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The *operator>> of* cin (which is an object of type basic_istream) reads and discards any leading whitespace (e.g. spaces, newlines, tabs). Then *operator>>* reads characters until the next whitespace character is encountered. The operators returns finally the stream itself, cin.
It shouldn't be possible to enter an empty string without also setting at least one of the iostates eof, fail or bad? And therefore the streams converts with the *operator bool* to false. I think *!buf.empty()* is here superfluous, but a good habit. Is there a way to leave the iostate of cin in *good* and leaving the string empty?

Example usage:
1. type in a word of your choice
2. press enter
3. press Ctrl+d (EOF on UNIX) or Ctrl+d (EOF on Windows)

Thank you

Comment: I'm pretty sure your `!buf.empty()` conjunction is spurious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not possible. If no characters could be extracted `std::ios::failbit` is set. [string.io]/3:

> If the function extracts no characters, it calls
>   `is.setstate(ios::failbit)`, which may throw `ios_base::failure`.

And if characters could be extracted they are subsequently appended to the `string` and thereby make its size non-zero.

Comment: Thank you! A brief note: The function keeps running as long as only whitespace was entered.