# Is the second condition in (cin >> buf && !buf.empty()) redundant?

Tags: c++, cin

I am following the C++ primer book, and got curious about the following code example:

```
string buf;
while (cin >> buf && !buf.empty()) {
    if (buf[0] != '_')
       continue; // get another input
       //the input starts with an underscore; process buf . . .
}
```

The loop should ignore words that do not start with an underscore and do something with the ones that do start with an underscore.

My question is about the condition

```
(cin >> buf && !buf.empty())
```

I would say that the condition (!buf.empty()) is always true when (cin >> buf) is true, so I do not see the point of adding it.
Is there any case when the second condition is not redundant?

There is a previous question on stack overflow about a similar construction ([Is it possible to read an empty string from cin and still get true from cin.good()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26818807/is-it-possible-to-read-an-empty-string-from-cin-and-still-get-true-from-cin-good)) whose answer is simply no (the second condition **is** redundant).

If this is correct, why is it on the book? It is simply an error?
Or there is some special situation were the double condition makes sense?

Comment: Well according to the question you linked, the second condition is redundant. In fact, your question almost seems like a duplicate of that one.

Comment: It is very strange to be in the book then. It seems that there is some special situation where this construction is useful.

Comment: This condition isn't needed at all. Your author is mistaken about the failure conditions of `std::operator>>(std::istream&, std::string&)`.

Comment: Thanks guys. I looked for this kind of construction in the internet and found only the similar `getline( cin, s ) && !s.empty()`, which makes sense, because the variable s can contain empty spaces as the result of getline. Maybe the author had this construction and later changed it to `(cin >> s)`, but forgot to remove the other redundant condition.

Comment: closing as duplicate: it really is the same question as the other one.  As to why the book has it: books contain mistakes or bad style. You could email the author or publisher with an erratum perhaps. There's no special situation.

Answer (score 1):

just to be clear, operator bool() is badbit || failbit, and the failbit is set when "an input operation failed to read the expected charchter or any other kind of operation failed to produce the desired result" (Langer, Kreft 1999)

```
string buf;
while ((cin >> buf,cin.operator bool()) && !buf.empty()) {
    if (buf[0] != '_')
       continue; // get another input
       //the input starts with an underscore; process buf . . .
}
```